# Liquibase Oracle OS Authentication

Tags: oracle, liquibase

We are trying to setup Liquibase in our environment, which is Oracle 12c running on AIX. Our schema owner is setup as an OS Authenticated account only allowed from the Oracle host server. When running Liquibase on the host server, logged in as the schema owner, we get ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied. Looking on the server, we see the username is blank. It's not trying to authenticate as the OS user. The properties file looks like this:

```
driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
classpath: /oracle_software/12.1.0.2/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:dbname
changeLogFile: dbchangelog.xml
```

We've tried giving a blank username and password, and also passing a "/". All result in the same ORA-01017 error.

Is it possible to use liquibase with OS Authentication in Oracle?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vince

Answer (score 0):

You can not use thin JDBC drivers for this purpose. Only jdbc-oci drivers do support 'connect / as sysdba'.

Comment: I changed thin to oci and it still isn't logging in. Do you know how to connect with / through Liquibase?